# How to add a php file to wordpress theme addition of standard files?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress themes have standard file such as header.php, footer.php, index.php, functions.php, style.css, ...
How to add a php file to wordpress theme addition of standard files? for example I want add a news.php to display specific posts in it, please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a new file (e.g. `news.php`), and put the template comment at the very beginning:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News Template
*/
```

Then, go to your Wordpress backend, create a new page, and select the template you created:

[image]

Comment: the Template is not anymore in Page Attributes for Wordpress 3.5.1

Comment: @lbennet - Interesting. I'm running 3.5.1, and its still there.