# How to add to a WordPress theme a page but a php file that is loaded separately

Tags: wordpress, themes

This seems to be an answer,
[How to add a php file to wordpress theme addition of standard files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240471/how-to-add-a-php-file-to-wordpress-theme-addition-of-standard-files)

Yet the template option is missing in my WordPress 3.5.1

How to do the same thing now with this currently the latest version of WordPress.

Or could it not be related to the WordPress version and actually has to do with a default setting of the theme not allowing for template choosing? Where could I look up for that in the theme configuration.

WordPress documentation didn't remove the Templates as part of the page attributes
http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-attributes/

So it could be related to the theme's options of not allowing for template choosing, would need to override that setting then maybe but don't know it's location now.

Comment: Got it working, had to reactivate the theme for it to pick up the template file. Activated another theme, then activated the theme that was being used and the template option appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Wordpress 3.5.1, the problem must be in your theme. Your current theme probably just doesn't have any additional templates you can use; try some others (like the default theme that came with your Wordpress installation, which is probably TwentyTwelve if you're running 3.5.1) and seeing if the template menu appears.

Answer (score 0):

Those templates are for (Wordpress terminology) **pages**, not posts. Posts do not have the "Page attributes" box, only pages.

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) appears to expand that functionality to posts.